# Excel formula for multiple conditions and worksheets

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

**The aim**

I am try to create a formula which will allow specific information from 90 different worksheets, with an example of one such worksheet being below. Each work sheet represents data from a participant.

[image]

I want the data from the 90 work sheets to be summarised into the worksheet below. [image]

**The problem**

The problem is that I need to create a formula that takes [counterbalancing](http://www.alleydog.com/glossary/definition.php?term=Counterbalance) into account.

So in cell A3 of the second image I would to record the number of times the value 1 and 3 appears in column I of the first image.

**The conditions**

However, I would only like the numbers in *column I* to count if:

a) in column M of image 1 there is a value of 1

and

b) when the number in *Column L* is 1 and *Column K* is 1 or 4 **OR** when the number in *Column L* is 2 and the number in *Column K* is 3 or 4.

**My attempt**

=SUM('[All_memories_301-389_improved.xlsx]Sirma 301:387Yanxin'!$M$2,1*(IF('[All_memories_301-389_improved.xlsx]Sirma 301:387Yanxin'!$L$2,1*(IF('[All_memories_301-389_improved.xlsx]Sirma 301:387Yanxin'!$K$2:$K$41,1,4*(IF('[All_memories_301-389_improved.xlsx]Sirma 301:387Yanxin'!$I$2:$I$54,1,3)))))))

This did not work however and I have spent a long time on this and made changes but I still can't seem to get it to work.

Extra information:

In column I I want to count all the occurrences of 1 and 3 provided the specified conditions are met. The rows are not important, but rather, the column I information for each of the 90 spreadsheets.

New attempt with formula:

=COUNTIFS('[All_memories_301-389_improved.xlsx]381Christie'!$M$2, 1, '[All_memories_301-389_improved.xlsx]381Christie'!$L$2, 1, '[All_memories_301-389_improved.xlsx]381Christie'!$K$2:$K$23, AND(1,4), '[All_memories_301-389_improved.xlsx]381Christie'!$I$2:$I$23, AND(1,3))

Comment: What do you want the row to count for if.. do you want to count the number of occurrences in the sheet?

Comment: It is almost always easier to make extra columns with intermediate results, than to get such complex formulas to work, so make a column with your conditions.

Comment: Hi Stephan, I'm not quite sure what you mean - can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you so much for adding extra detail to your comment. To make sure I understood, you mean make one column that has the condition numbers in it? Currently several columns already represent the conditions. If certain conditions are met then information should be counted. I've added a new attempt to do this problem in my answer. As I have 90 set of data my PhD supervisor suggested to try to an excel formula and that it's quite easy though I'm trying to figure it out still. So I agree that your idea is better but my supervisor likes things his way and he is not the type to help.